# Android LiveData and DataBinding - problem with numbers

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-livedata

Iam using a LiveData with DataBindg.
My ViewModel:

```
private val _counter = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val counter: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _counter
```

In init blok it is set to 0.

```
init {
    _counter.value = 0
```

In activity:

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

Data binding in view:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.counter}"
```

After running application shut down on error because it try to get value of counter 0 and put it to getString method which when parameter is Int try to find string resource.
Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

It try to run generated code in ClickMeBindingImpl.java

```
if ((dirtyFlags & 0x31L) != 0) {
    // api target 1
    this.clickCounterText.setText(androidxDatabindingViewDataBindingSafeUnboxViewModelCounterGetValue);
        }
```

Do you know why?

My solution is:
`android:text="@{viewModel.counter+` `}"`
or nicer solution:

```
<string name="number">%d</string>
...
android:text="@{@string/number(viewModel.counter)}"
```

Do you know if I doing it wrong or why it do mot know that counter is Int and i want to put value of Int to a view?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewmodel.counter`  inside **layout xml file** is  referring to **ViewModel's counter** variable which is of type **Int.**

`android:text` attribute requires value of type **String**.

To solve it, you have to use `android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewmodel.counter)}"` which actually returns a **String representation of Int**.

**In your layout xml file just replace**:

`android:text="@{viewModel.counter}"` with  `android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewmodel.counter)}"`